# Install "libgiblib.so.1()(64bit)" on Fedora31 when it is not avaible

Tags: pyautogui

I am trying to install "scrot" on Fedora 31 and It requires that packet "libgiblib.so.1()(64bit)".

```
localhost python]$ sudo dnf install scrot
Fedora Modular 31 - x86_64 - Updates             52 kB/s |  42 kB     00:00    
Fedora 31 - x86_64 - Updates                     49 kB/s |  40 kB     00:00    
Fedora 31 - x86_64 - Updates                    601 kB/s | 2.4 MB     00:04    
Error: 
 Problema: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libgiblib.so.1()(64bit) needed by scrot-0.8-21.fc31.x86_64
(pruebe a añadir '--skip-broken' para descartar los paquetes que no se pueden instalar)
```

I downloaded Giblib-1.2.4-28.x86_64 that provides libgiblib.so.1()(64bit) (according to: [Fedora Pkgs](https://fedora.pkgs.org/31/rpm-sphere-x86_64/giblib-1.2.4-28.x86_64.rpm.html) )

```
[pc@localhost Descargas]$ sudo rpm -i giblib-1.2.4-28.x86_64.rpm
    el paquete giblib-1.2.4-28.x86_64 ya está instalado
```

but when I try to download again, it sends me the same message:

```
[pc@localhost Descargas]$ sudo dnf install scrot
Última comprobación de caducidad de metadatos hecha hace 0:26:36, el lun 03 feb 2020 08:16:27 -03.
Error: 
 Problema: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libgiblib.so.1()(64bit) needed by scrot-0.8-21.fc31.x86_64
(pruebe a añadir '--skip-broken' para descartar los paquetes que no se pueden instalar)
```

Do you know what I could do?? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Note: This is a third party package not officially from fedora]

Go to this link [libgiblib.so.1()(64bit)](https://fedora.pkgs.org/32/rpm-sphere-x86_64/giblib-1.2.4-28.x86_64.rpm.html) and download the binary package listed here.

First to install the dependencies run

```
dnf install imlib2

dnf install glibc
```

Install libgiblib.so.1()(64bit)

```
rpm -Uvh path-to-rpm-file-you-downloaded
```

Now you can install scrot with following

```
dnf install scrot
```

Comment: original link is gone, got the libgiblib.so.1() package for Fedora 31 from here(although it's for Fedora 30, works on 31):  https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/30/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/g/giblib-1.2.4-28.fc28.x86_64.rpm

Comment: I ended up using `shutter` which appears to work out of the box in fedora 32: `sudo dnf install -y shutter`

Answer (score 1):

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rpmsphere/x86_64/master/g/giblib-1.2.4-28.x86_64.rpm
sudo  rpm -Uvh giblib-1.2.4-28.x86_64.rpm
sudo dnf install scrot
```